# adobe acrobat dc document level javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

Of course as I search the forums, search google search results all of the answers are for a previous version of adobe acrobat before they decided to change everything.  I can not find where I can insert *document level javascript* in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.  There is no "Tools" or "Advanced" menu anymore which is pretty much every answer I've seen so far.  Does anybody on here know how to quickly add document level javascript to a pdf in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC so I can add global functions that I can call anywhere and assign some global data that these functions work off of?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you talking about document-level scripts (working within the document) or application-level scripts (working for any document)?

Comment: @MaxWyss - only on the document level at this time.

Comment: OK, in this case you can follow my answer below.

Comment: @MaxWyss - *slaps hand on forehead* of course it's in the tools section all the way down at the bottom.  OK, I have a handle on it.  Frees me up from duplicating code uselessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Acrobat DC, you have the Tools view, where you will find the JavaScript tool. You then can add it to the Right Hand Panel. The JavaScript tool has the long known options.

You also can use the Tool Search feature in the Right Hand Panel (note: in some Acrobat DC versions, under certain circumstances, this can crash Acrobat; but I think they did fix that bug in the meantime; get the newest version).

Comment: yes the top one works.  I was doing some testing.  Now it's about trying to get it to work right under the broadest conditions.  Preview just erases all javascript once you start inputting into a calculated field and chrome works in calculating fields but custom links don't work.  This is a very squirrely environment to run JavaScript.